# Assertion the value of element is not more than 0

Tags: xpath, robotframework, assertion

How do I assert the value of "Points" is not not more than 0?

This is the web element

```
<div style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(51, 17, 17); font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 9px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 15px;" xpath="1">Points: 0</div>
```

I am using wait for element state

```
*** Settings ***
Resource            ../Resources/BrowserFunctions.robot
Suite Setup         Start New Browser
Test Setup          Test Setup
Test Teardown       Test Teardown
Suite Teardown      Close Browser

*** Test Cases ***
001_test
     Tick Stats Widget Checkbox
     wait for elements state        //div[normalize-space()='Points: 0']
```

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the most efficient way...

-First get the text of the element

```
${Point}=    Get text |  element
```

-Get substring to get the '0'

```
${Point}=    Get substring  |   ${Point}    |   -1
```

-Convert to integer

```
${Point}=    convert to integer   |   ${Point}
```

-Check if its not 0

```
should not be equal as integers   |  ${Point}   |     0
```

Comment: Just change getting a substring with regex (the value may  be 2 or more digits) and the solution is very solid.

Comment: @TodorMinakov could you let me know how to do it regex?

Comment: @etoprak the xpath will change , the points will be 0, 200, 600.....it varies when connected to external hardware sensor. in this case , if current element xpath="1">Points: 200< , then how do I verify it?

Comment: @guo That's a good question, I did not know it could go that high. But a solution for that would be creating if statements on the length of the whole string (like 'Points: 300'). 

So for example if the length is 9 (single number) you do a substring of the last character and if the length is 10 do a substring of the last 2 characters  and so on

Comment: @etoprak any sample how to do if else with such conditions?

Comment: @guo 
[link to if example](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#if-expression)
Under 2.9.4 the if expression is explained with a sample

Comment: @etoprak thanks. not sure how do I detect the actual , how many decimal points.